# Why are the "Trilogy" Stack Exchange sites the only ones that display ads?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, advertising

I noticed that, as far as I can tell, the "Trilogy" Stack Exchange sites,

1. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
2. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
3. [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

are the only ones that display non-Stack Exchange ads (i.e. ads for other Stack Exchanges or the iOS and Android apps), like the following (from Stack Overflow):

[image: Stack Overflow ad]

### Stack Exchange's Business Model

According to Jeff's answer in [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model/79448#79448), besides generating revenue from job listings and candidate search, **Stack Exchange also makes money through ads**:

> Traditional, but respectful (e.g. no animation or flash or pop-anything) display advertising on SO, SF, and to a lesser extent SU.

If such is the case, **then why don't any of the other exchanges also display ads?** The [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) exchange is the [3<sup>rd</sup> most heavily trafficked exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) (beating out Server Fault), and yet it displays no ads (as far as I could tell), and I would have thought that [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) would be a perfect site for displaying game ads, and yet it doesn't.

Does Stack Exchange have any plans to display ads on these sites in the future?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69429/will-stack-exchange-2-0-websites-stay-free-of-ads-for-the-next-2-years